# How to retrieve a TextEditingController inside a Controller layer with Getx?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have this statement in my View layer

```
TextEditingController controllerDestino = TextEditingController();
```

And I want to recover this controllerDestino, to use within a method that is in my Controller layer.

```
 statusUberNaoChamado() {
showBoxAdress = true;

changeMainButton("Chamar", Color(0xFF1ebbd8), () {
  callUber("I need pass the controller here");
});

update();}
```

Thank you in advance for your attention :)

Comment: You mean to say you want send the text editing controller value to `callUber` function right?

Comment: I have the method: callUber (TextEditingController controller) {###}.

So for me to call this method within another method, I need to pass this TextEditingController parameter.

The problem is, the callUber () method I'm calling directly from the View layer, where the TextEditingController is instantiated, so I can easily recover.

But statusUberNaoChamado () method is inside the Controller layer and I was wondering how can I retrieve the TextEditingController instance that is in the View layer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define/instantiate the TextEditingController as a field inside your GetxController you're using to control your form / implement business logic.

```
class DestinoFormControllerX extends GetxController {
  static DestinoFormControllerX get i => Get.find();
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> key = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  // ↓ place the text editing controller inside your... controller :)
  var controllerDestino = TextEditingController();
```

And use the TextEditingController values wherever you need in your GetxController

```
  void resetForm() {
    key.currentState.reset();
    controllerDestino.text = '';
    focusNode.requestFocus();
  }
```

In your View layer, inject your GetxController, and get the text editing controller & access any other methods/fields you need.

```
class DestinoForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() submitHandler;

  DestinoForm({this.submitHandler});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dcx = Get.put(DestinoFormControllerX());
    // ↑ inject GetxController, be careful to put *inside* build method

    return FormBuilder(
      key: dcx.key,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FormBuilderTextField(
            name: 'destino',
            controller: dcx.controllerDestino,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Destino',
            ),
```

Most forms would have Reset & Submit buttons.  There you can call methods on your GetxController....

```
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Reset'),
          onPressed: () => DestinoFormControllerX.i.resetForm(),
        ),
```

#### Side Note

If you're instantiating / injecting your GetxController in your Form Widget with `Get.put()`, do so **inside the `build` method** of your Form Widget.

Otherwise, you'll likely have `TextEditingController`s calling `setState` on a StatefulWidget (the textfield) that is no longer mounted in the widget tree:

```
════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for TextEditingController:
setState() called after dispose(): _FormBuilderTextFieldState#96390(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
```

#### Good

```
class DestinoForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() submitHandler;

  DestinoForm({this.submitHandler});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dcx = Get.put(DestinoFormControllerX());
    // ↑ inject GetxController, be careful to put *inside* build method
```

#### Bad

```
class DestinoForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() submitHandler;
  final dcx = Get.put(DestinoFormControllerX());
  // ↑ wrong place, DestinoFormControllerX gets linked to previous route

  DestinoForm({this.submitHandler});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

[More detail on Github](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/384), mentioning proper injection / usage of GetX.

Comment: You're off to a good start in choosing GetX for State Management.  There's some good videos linked here that can help you get up to speed: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/wiki/Community-Tutorials-and-Examples

Answer (score 2):

I faced with same problem again and found my question after one year.

It's seems that controller should be declared:

```
final foo = TextEditingController().obs;
```

And be accessed with:

```
TextField(
 controller: Get.find<SearchFormController>().foo.value,
 keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
),
```

getting value:

```
print(Get.find<SearchFormController>().foo.value.text);
```